# Which warp tool should i use for this kind of smooth curve in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was trying to make this kind of smooth curve for very long time[image]
 [image]
but this is what i get so far the bending point of my image is not properly positioned and i couldn't make the distance from bottom point to bending point. i mean, it bends/curves too early.I couldn't make it curve properly as reference photo, i used warp>lower shell for my image. please give me some suggestion!

Answer (score 7):

I would prefer doing this job by using any 3D package just for accuracy.

But we can do it using Illustrator. and here you are my solution.

1. First prepare the wooden floor texture and insert it into Illustrator by drag and drop onto your artboard or by place image, go to `File > Place` or click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select the texture you have it. For that tutorial I will use floor texture that that [link](https://answers.unrealengine.com/storage/temp/61433-my-ipe-3-lg-scale-rotated.jpg). make sure that your texture be in high resolution.
2. you can use that texture in several ways, you can make it as a `fill patter` or just tile it as separated image (in case you don't want to tile your texture). that decision depend on what if the pattern could be tiled perfectly or not, to not let any gapes appears in your final product.
3. I Will use the "Filling Pattern Method", so after inserting your texture in your artboard, drag and drop it in the color swatch panel, to make make it as pattern fill.

[image]

4. Draw a rectangle and fill it with the pattern we have just did.
5. Rasterize the rectangle to prepare ti wrap it. by going to `Object > Rasterize...`
6. Now we are ready to build our wrap, but before that we will make some guides to help us doing a perfect perspective, like the hereunder screen shoot.

[image]

7. We are ready to wrap the texture using "Envelope distort". Select the Filled Rectangle with the black arrow and go to `Object > envelope Distor > Make with Mesh...` or Click <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>. a Dialouge box will appear, make 3 rows and 1 column.

[image]

8. With the white arrow place the control point of the generated mesh over the guidelines we just made it as shown hereunder.
9. Now adjust the control point handles to match the direction of the floor for perfect perspective.

[image]

[image]

10. this is the end result, you can make a `Clipping Mask` to match the screenshot you bring. by drawing a rectangle over the texture we just wrapped. and select all your artworks and go to `Object > Clipping Mask > Make` or click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>. That's it.

[image]

[image]

as you can notice the texture is not perfectly rounded that's why I would prefer a 3D package to do the job.

11. For adding some refection to the curved floor I use the mesh gradient tool to highlight the curve as follow

[image]

12. and in the opacity panel in the top properties bar select "Overlay" as a color blended mood.

[image]

[image]

13. with the white arrow tool while holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> select the surrounding controls point over the mesh gradient tool and in the opacity panel make the opacity equal Zero.
14. stretch the gradient mesh to cover the ground floor.

    and Voila !!

[image]

Comment: You could use rule of thirds so your borads would not bulge so much